# What are the best methods to study violin positions?

Tags: violin, exercises

I play on a few songs in other locations but am not an expert on them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, pick a position that you want to focus on. Play through scales of pieces that you will use the position on, practicing shifting in and out of those positions. Don't necessarily play your scales in order - shift around notes on them to be able to simulate how pieces might play, and go all over the fingerboard.

If you are struggling with intonation, laying down tape to mark locations may also work.

I don't think there will be a substitute for this rather than practice, but you can get creative with it - improvise in different positions over scales, for example, if playing rote scales is boring.

Comment: About intonation you can also transform the music to midi format (audio) to play along with it, using some sheet music editor like [MuseScore](https://musescore.org), [Rosegarden](http://www.rosegardenmusic.com), [Denemo](http://www.denemo.org) etc.

Answer (score 2):

Take out your copy of the "Bach violin solo sonatas and partitas" urtexts and pick out the pieces that are monophonic preferringly containing an ample amount of slurs.  Try not to break slurs or other obvious phrases across strings.

That makes for a solid amount of exercise for 2nd position but also 3rd and 4th.

Comment: BWV 1001-1006 can be found here [http://imslp.org/wiki/6_Violin_Sonatas_and_Partitas,_BWV_1001-1006_(Bach,_Johann_Sebastian)](http://imslp.org/wiki/6_Violin_Sonatas_and_Partitas,_BWV_1001-1006_(Bach,_Johann_Sebastian))

Answer (score 2):

Lots of study books tackle higher positions, for example

- [Otakar Ševčík's School of Violin Technique Op. 1 Part 2](http://www.boosey.com/shop/prod/Sevcik-Otakar-Viola-Studies-Op-1Pt2/675442) and
- [Mary Cohen's Nifty Shifts](http://www.fabermusic.com/repertoire/nifty-shifts-4367)

And some pieces are written to help beginners explore other positions, for example

- [David Sone's Eight Pieces in the Third Position](http://www.boosey.com/shop/prod/Stone-David-Eight-Pieces-in-the-Third-Position/642190)

Such studies will help you feel secure out of first position, and (as [tarun mentions](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/30247/2125)) scales will too.

Comment: Sevcik's method can be found here: http://imslp.org/wiki/School_of_Violin_Technique,_Op.1_(%C5%A0ev%C4%8D%C3%ADk,_Otakar)